# how we can limit the send requests using sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector through facebook Api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

plz see this link, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ , i used it to send request through dialog box sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector using facebook api, now i just want to put a limit of max 4 so that we can send request max of 4 people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same page you linked in your question, at the bottom there's a table of possible parameters to be used with this specific dialog.
One of those parameter is the *max_recipients* parameter and it says:

> An integer that specifies the maximum number of friends that can be
>   chosen by the user in the friend selector. This parameter is not
>   supported on mobile devices.

So basically:

```
FB.ui({
    method: "apprequests",
    message: "Hey, come see this app",
    max_recipients: 4
}, requestCallback);
```